# dpkg error /var/lib/dpkg/status

Tags: debian, files, dpkg

I m under debian8 and some (important) files have been deleted. I m trying to restore my machine and almost everything works except `dpkg-query -l`, it returns me those lines :

```
root@minos:~# dpkg-query -l
dpkg-query : erreur : la lecture du fichier « info » « /var/lib/dpkg/status » 
du paquet a échoué: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

It looks like the file at `/var/lib/dpkg/status` doesn't exist anymore. Is that possible to 're-create' one ? Thanks

**EDIT**

```
root@minos:~# ls -lrt /var/lib/dpkg/
total 156
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 mai    3  2016 parts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 mai   18 09:26 updates
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 mai   23 16:25 alternatives
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 mai   23 16:25 triggers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 139264 mai   23 16:25 info
-rw-r----- 1 root root      0 mai   24 11:45 lock
```

This doesn't work..

```
root@minos:~# cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
cp: impossible d'évaluer « /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 »: Aucun fichier ou 
dossier de ce type
root@minos:~# ls -lrt /var/backups/
total 64
-rw------- 1 root root     870 mai   17 11:42 group.bak
-rw------- 1 root shadow   728 mai   17 11:42 gshadow.bak
-rw------- 1 root shadow  1445 mai   17 11:42 shadow.bak
-rw------- 1 root root    1821 mai   17 11:42 passwd.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   33242 mai   18 09:08 apt.extended_states.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10240 mai   25 06:25 alternatives.tar.0
```

Comment: `cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status`  then `apt update && apt upgrade`

Comment: Please in the future, post the commands as `LANG=C command` as in `LANG=C dpkg-query -l` so the error messages are displayed in English.

Comment: I guess my last solution is to reinstall debian...